# Program works in terminal but "timed out while waiting for program to exit" in Check50

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to programming and this is my first time posting here so please excuse me if the answer is painfully obvious!

I encountered this error when working on [pset1](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/1/mario/less/) from CS50x 2019. We're supposed to print a pyramid with a height between 1 and 8 inclusive, and the program needs to re-prompt the user if the height entered is out of this range.

When I ran the program in the terminal, it works as intended every time... but not according to Check50. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my code or is this more of a Check50 problem? This is my [result](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/15a57ee20798b8862274bec647a843a35878b589) from Check50.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h> // for printf function
#include <cs50.h> // for get_int function
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep function

int main(void)
{
    // prompt user for height; reprompt if input is less than 1 or greater than 8
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (h < 1 || h > 8);

    // outer loop prints r rows; inner loop prints c columns
    for (int r = 0; r < h; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < h; c++)
        {
            if (c < h - 1 - r)
            {
                printf(".");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
    printf("\n");
    sleep(1);
    }
}
```

[screenshot with input 8 showing the pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xhlb.png)

Comment: *When I ran the program in the terminal, it works as intended every time.* What input have you tried? Your program does not output properly for any input from 2 till 8.

Comment: When I tried 0, 9, ".", -1, it prompted me to re-enter. When I tried 2 to 8, it printed the pyramid... I'll update the post with a screenshot with input 8 showing the pyramid.

Comment: Are you sure the `sleep(1);` calls inside the `for` loops aren't causing the timeout?  Taking 72 seconds to produce an 8-level pyramid is a tad excessive.  On my machine, I don't see each character as it is printed, even, because there is no `fflush(stdout)` to force the characters to the screen (so it takes about 9 seconds per line).  Comment out the `sleep()` calls and there's a decent chance your code will pass the Check50 testing without a timeout.

Comment: That worked! Oh man, I was trying to use the sleep function to understand how the code would print "in slow mo" but turned out it was the issue. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting my comment into an answer.*</sup>

Are you sure the `sleep(1);` calls inside the for loops aren't causing the timeout?

It takes about 72 seconds to produce an 8-level pyramid, which is a tad excessive. On my machine, I don't even see each character as it is printed because there is no `fflush(stdout)` to force the characters to the screen (so it takes about 9 seconds per line).

Comment out the `sleep()` calls and there's a decent chance your code will pass the Check50 testing without a timeout.